# Populate a JavaScript array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I have an array like below:

```
    var list = [
    {name: "1", lastname: "foo1"},
    {name: "2", lastname: "foo"},
    {name: "3", lastname: "foo1"}
];
```

I need to know how to create an empty array called "list" and populate it dynamically with above properties and values. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I need to populate the array with the push() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var list = [];
list.push({name: "1", lastname: "foo1"});
list.push({name: "2", lastname: "foo"});
list.push({name: "3", lastname: "foo1"});
```

**[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** is the documentation about pushing values in arrays.

---

Simplified you can also push all the values in the array calling the function once:

```
var list = [];
list.push({name: "1", lastname: "foo1"}, 
    {name: "2", lastname: "foo"},
    {name: "3", lastname: "foo1"});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Array.map()

```
var copy = list.map(function(item){
    return item;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Array.map() is pretty powerful, it basically takes each item of the array, passes it into the callback function, where you can do any sorts of transformations or operations, and pushes it into a new array.